# Android: app name and icon from activity name string

Tags: android, android-activity, package, android-package-managers

My Android app stores some activity names of external apps to be launched later.

Example: "com.companyname.app.ActivityName"

The app name and the icon have to be retrieved from just this string.

I am using this kind of code:

```
intent=new Intent("com.companyname.app.ActivityName");
label=packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(intent.getPackage(),0)).toString();
icon=packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(intent.getPackage(),0));
```

but it seems that the intent is not well formed, or the instructions are wrong.

How to get the requested values?

Comment: Why are you using an Intent to wrap the package name? Just call `getApplicationLabel()` passing the package name as a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity class name alone does not suffice to identify it unambiguously. You also need to have the package name for that. Then you can create a [ComponentName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html) and an intent to start this activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(action).setComponent(new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
```

With the same component name and the package manager's [`getActivityInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getActivityInfo%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29) you could also access the [ActivityInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html) and get the label and icon of the activity itself.

But in your example you're using the [Intent(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String%29) constructor to define an action of `"com.companyname.app.ActivityName"` to be started.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a bad idea to store activity names of other packages. The app
   developer might release an updated version which no longer has an
   Activity with that name.
2. The `Intent` constructor you are using sets the *action* of the
   `Intent`. It currently has no package.

I would only store the package name of the target app and use that to get the information about that app.

```
String packageName = ...;
try {
    String label = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageName);
    Drawable icon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName);
    // etc.
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get info for package " + packageName);
}
```

If you then need to launch that app, use [`packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)) to get an `Intent` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
  android:name=".ui.HomeActivity"
  android:label="@string/title_home_activity"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```